# Handling onMessageReceived function for push notifications: NativeScript

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, nativescript

I'm developing an android app with NativeScript which includes push notifications functionality.
Whenever push message is coming I have to save the message details.For implementing this functionality I used onMessageReceived function.

```
App.js file:::::

var application=require("application");
var applicationSettings = require("application-settings");
application.mainModule="Registration/Registration";
// application.mainModule="CreateTask/CreateTask";
application.css="styles/Follow.css";
application.start();
application.on(application.launchEvent, function (args) {
if (args.android) {
    var gcm = require("nativescript-push-notifications");
    gcm.register({ senderID: '616557539872' }, function (data) {
        console.log("message"+ JSON.stringify(data));
    }, function () { });
        gcm.onMessageReceived(function callback(data) {
            console.log("message received:::: ", "" + JSON.stringify(data));
         //  some code for storing notification contents to database
            var notifications=require("~/notifications");
             notifications.createViewModel(data);

        });

} else if (args.ios !== undefined) {
    //Do ios stuff here
}
});
```

**notifications.js**

```
var LocalNotifications = require("nativescript-local-notifications");
var dialogs = require("ui/dialogs");
var frameModule=require("ui/frame");

var notifications=new Object();
function doAddOnMessageReceivedCallback() {
console.log("doAddOnMessageReceivedCallback::");
LocalNotifications.addOnMessageReceivedCallback(
    function(notificationData) {

        frameModule.topmost().navigate("Registration/Registration");
        dialogs.alert({
            title: "Notification received",
            message: "ID: " + notificationData.id +
            "\nTitle: " + notificationData.title +
            "\nBody: " + notificationData.body,
            okButtonText: "Excellent!"
        });
    }
);
}

function createViewModel(data) {
    console.log("createViewModel::"+data); 
    doAddOnMessageReceivedCallback();
    LocalNotifications.schedule([{
        id: 0,
        title: "AddTaskNotification",
        body: data,
        ticker: this.ticker,
        at: new Date(new Date().getTime())
    }]).then(() => {
        console.log("Notification scheduled");
    }, (error) => {
        console.log("ERROR", error);
    });

}

exports.createViewModel = createViewModel;
```

**permissions in app->App_Resources->Android->AndroidManifest.xml**

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>`

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>`

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>`

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />`

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />`

`<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE"/>`

**Manifest file contents under: node_modules->nativescript-push-notifications->platforms->android->AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<application>
    <activity android:name="com.telerik.pushplugin.PushHandlerActivity"/>
    <receiver
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <category android:name="com.pushApp.gcm" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <service
            android:name="com.telerik.pushplugin.PushPlugin"
            android:exported="false" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
</application>
```

In onMessageReceived function I'm performing some action and then triggering a local notification.I'm doing like this because if I gave onMessageReceived function then notification is not showing in notification bar.So I'm trigger local notification after saving to db.

If app is running then contents of onMessageReceived function is executing.
How ever if app is closed then contents of onMessageReceived is not executing(even console.log also not executing).

How to handle data in onMessageReceived function when app is closed?

Any suggestions will be Helpful.Thanks.

Comment: A nice how-to article on that matter can be found here : https://bradmartin.net/2015/12/28/use-google-cloud-messaging-for-push-notifications-with-nativescript/

Comment: Hi, Thanks for reply.I followed the same tutorial to implement pushnotifications concept.But the problem is I need to perform some operation in onMessageReceived function.But that function is not executing if app is closed.Can you give any suggestions??

Comment: @Karteek Did you ever find a solution to this problem? I'm having the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Please check this plug-in: https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/nativescript-local-notifications

This could be what you need

**EDIT:**

I notice something, that you are checking the onMessageReceived; please try this code instead:

```
var gcm=require("nativescript-push-notifications");
gcm.onMessageReceived(function callback(data) { 
   console.log("message received:::: ", "" + JSON.stringify(data));
   // code related to saving the details... 
});
```

Also did you set correctly the android permissions??

Comment: Thanks for the reply.Previously I tried localnotifications but that also not working for my special condition(if app is closed).As you suggested I removed onMessageReceived checking and then tried, but now also no working if app is closed.I edited my post with the updated code for the reference(removing onMessageReceived check,implemented localnotification).If I'm doing any mistakes, please correct me.

Comment: Yes i did same, scheduled notification after 1 sec. on receiving push notification. But when app is closed so at that time local notification does not schedule and hence it doesn't show up.